# Multiply input values in Strut2 form submit

Tags: java, struts2, tomcat6

I am working in struts2, using tomcat server. I am uploading a file and I have text input in my form submit.

Where I am able to find the interceptor, which will work for fileupload and text input, here you can find my struts.xml for my form action.

```
<action name="IMageUpload"  class="com.uniphore.action.ManageClientAction" method="Image">
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximumSize">1000000</param>
                <param name="allowedTypes">
                    image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,text/plain
                </param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">Image</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

### My form as follows

```
<s:form action ="ImageUpload">
 <s:file name="upload">
 <s:textfield name"user">
 <s:submit  method="Image"/>
</s:form>
```

When i submit this form i am getting error like this

```
ParametersInterceptorUnexpected Exception catched: Error setting expression 'user' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@322e7d'
```

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Are you asking how to read text values and upload a file at the same time?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My form contain <s:form action ="ImageUpload"><s:file name="upload"><s:text name"user"></s:form>, When i submit this form i am getting error like this ParametersInterceptorUnexpected Exception catched: Error setting expression 'user' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@322e7d'

Comment: Err... if you want the user to input value in `<s:text name"user">`, put `<s:textfield name="user"/>` instead.

Comment: Should be a multipart form, too.

Comment: how with multiple sumbit

Comment: @Mohan What do you mean, "multiple submit"? I see a single submit. How? By setting the `enctype` as with any HTML form.

Comment: but my requiredment to do by single submit , is that any how i can do it